# How to customize the emacs plugin called hl-tags-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization, text-editor, highlighting

After switching to Emacs for editing purposes, I have started missing the way Notepad++ does tag highlighting.

When I move the caret/cursor to an HTML tag, the opposite end of the tag should be highlighted.

The Emacs plugin called `hl-tags-mode` does this, but how can I change it so that

1. the highlighting happens only when cursor is at an
   HTML tag. Right now the plugin highlights even when cursor
   is inside some plain text inside a parent tag.
2. Only the opposite end should be highlighted.
   So if I'm at a `<div>` tag, only the matching `</div>`
   should be highlighted. And vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

`show-paren-mode` would probably be the right mode for that, but it currently doesn't do it for HTML tags.  Try `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking for that new feature.